# Accessing element dynamically from scope angular

Tags: angularjs, validation, variables, dynamic, scope

In a directive like below how can we set validation manually on other element passed through attributes in directive. Code below gives error otherField does not exist while it should take value of this variable and not directly name of this field in scope string.

```
app.directive('higherThan', [
  function() {

    var link = function($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl) {

      var otherField = $attrs.otherField;
      $scope.otherField.$setValidity('lowerThan', true);
      //Other details of directive not kept for simplicity
    }

    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: link
    };

  }
]);
```

HTML

```
<form name="main_form">
<label>From</label>

<input name="from_date" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="date_range[0]" lower-than="date_range[1]" ng-required="true" close-text="Close"  />

<label>To</label>

<input name="to_date" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="date_range[1]" higher-than="date_range[0]" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" other-field="from_date"/>

<span ng-show="main_form.to_date.$error.higherThan">From date should be lower than to date</span>
</form>
```

Comment: could you show us your html too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var otherField = $attrs.otherField;
$scope.otherField.$setValidity('lowerThan', true);
```

There are a few of issues here:

1) `var otherField` is a string, not the actual input.

2) Once you've set `var otherField` you're not actually using it for anything.

3) There's no property `$scope.otherField`, which is why you're getting the error.

Even if you did `$scope[otherField]` this would error, as the ngModelController for `from_date` does not belong to `$scope` it belongs to `main_form`.

You should try using `console.log($scope)` to investigate.

It should be:

```
app.directive('higherThan', [
    function($parse) {

        var link = function($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl) {

            var otherField = $parse($attrs.otherField)($scope);
            otherField.$setValidity('lowerThan', true);
            //Other details of directive not kept for simplicity
        }

        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: link
        };

    }
]);


<form name="main_form">
  <label>From</label>
  <input name="from_date" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="date_range[0]" lower-than="date_range[1]" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
  <label>To</label>
  <input name="to_date" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="date_range[1]" higher-than="date_range[0]" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" other-field="main_form.from_date" />
  <span ng-show="main_form.to_date.$error.higherThan">From date should be lower than to date</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, was confused about parse stuff and converting string to variable names!

Answer (score 0):

`$setValidity` should be called on `NgModelController` object:

```
var link = function($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl) {

    var otherField = $attrs.otherField;
    ctrl.$setValidity('lowerThan', true);
    //Other details of directive not kept for simplicity
}
```